# execute code in remote linux machine

Tags: linux

I need to execute shell script on my remote linux machine. Do you know any tools that can help me doing that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect through ssh passing a command as a parameter:

```
ssh user@remote.ip.address "~/myscript.sh"
```

To connect without password, use ssh keys. To use keys, you have to generate a pair at your machine, with the command:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then take the contents of the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (or id_dsa.pub if you use parameter -t dsa in ssh-keygen) and put in the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of the remote_machine. The .ssh dir must have permission 700.

Comment: i my script i have "sudo ...", i got an error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: yes, sudo is asking your password but there is no way the password can be asked to you. use the command "visudo" as root to edit the sudo permissions and add a NOPASSWD to your user config, something like this: youruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Most Linux distros include `ssh-copy-id`, which will handle all of the steps after `ssh-keygen`. Thus, no need to copy the public key or worry about file permissions.

Comment: thanks for the tip about visuo. But i run into another problem after that. In my script, i execute ant and in my ant build script, it has if statement in there, and ant doesn't seems to load library correctly. It looks like what ever shell I log into my machine is very limited. Is there a way to make it load just like I normally log into my machine?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe the -t ssh option have something to do with this. -t forces psudo-tty allocation.

Comment: maybe this also has something to do with your environment. if you just type "set" you'll see all environment variables. maybe if you do "ssh user@host 'set > set.txt'" you can look for what's missing there

Answer (score 1):

For Python you can use [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to run commands on the remote computer over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Passwordless remote execution without waiting for remote script to complete before terminating the ssh connection:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@remote nohup sh /path/to/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to execute a local script on remote host

`ssh remotePassword@remoteHost < localScript.sh`

2. If you want to invoke a script on remote host

`ssh remotePassword@remoteHost "remoteScript.sh"`